# @PropertySource with the right classpath

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, microservices

I have a microservice (name = "microservice-porting.jar") inside a directory "/opt/microservice-porting/". Inside the directory, I have a  config folder
with an application properties file application.yml.

The structure is:

```
microservice-porting/
    microservice-porting.jar
    config/
        application.yaml
```

In my code:

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:/microservice-porting/config/application.yml", factory = MultipleYamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
```

but i always get exception:

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
> [microservice-porting/config/application.yml] cannot be opened because
> it does not exist

All these files and directories are at a remote server where i deploy the jar files.

**What is the right classpath for may case?**

Comment: You don't as Spring Boot will already load this, you don't need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the `application.yml` file located in the `config` folder, specify the classpath as follows:

```java
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:/config/application.yml", factory = MultipleYamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
```

Make sure the `config` folder is located in the same directory as your JAR file.